# GCP Pub/Sub Client, GrpcSubscriberStub, Timeout

Tags: java, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm trying use GrpcSubscriberStub for "Synchronous Pull" as 
in examples https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull

```
SubscriberStubSettings subscriberStubSettings =
    SubscriberStubSettings.newBuilder()
        .setTransportChannelProvider(
            SubscriberStubSettings.defaultGrpcTransportProviderBuilder()
                .setMaxInboundMessageSize(20 << 20) // 20MB
                .build())
        .build();

try (SubscriberStub subscriber = GrpcSubscriberStub.create(subscriberStubSettings)) {
  // String projectId = "my-project-id";
  // String subscriptionId = "my-subscription-id";
  // int numOfMessages = 10;   // max number of messages to be pulled
  String subscriptionName = ProjectSubscriptionName.format(projectId, subscriptionId);
  PullRequest pullRequest =
      PullRequest.newBuilder()
          .setMaxMessages(numOfMessages)
          .setReturnImmediately(false) // return immediately if messages are not available
          .setSubscription(subscriptionName)
          .build();

  // use pullCallable().futureCall to asynchronously perform this operation
  PullResponse pullResponse = subscriber.pullCallable().call(pullRequest);
  List<String> ackIds = new ArrayList<>();
  for (ReceivedMessage message : pullResponse.getReceivedMessagesList()) {
    // handle received message
    // ...
    ackIds.add(message.getAckId());
  }
  // acknowledge received messages
  AcknowledgeRequest acknowledgeRequest =
      AcknowledgeRequest.newBuilder()
          .setSubscription(subscriptionName)
          .addAllAckIds(ackIds)
          .build();
  // use acknowledgeCallable().futureCall to asynchronously perform this operation
  subscriber.acknowledgeCallable().call(acknowledgeRequest);
  return pullResponse.getReceivedMessagesList();
}
```

But i don't see how i can set a timeout for pull, with option "setReturnImmediately(false)".

Can you help me?

Comment: Please post a [mre] of the code that is causing the problem in your answer

Answer (score 1):

To change the pull timeout, you'll need to modify your `SubscriberStubSettings`.

For example, to set the total timeout of pull to 30 seconds:

```
SubscriberStubSettings.Builder subscriberStubSettingsBuilder =
    SubscriberStubSettings.newBuilder();
subscriberStubSettingsBuilder
    .pullSettings()
    .setRetrySettings(
        subscriberStubSettingsBuilder.pullSettings().getRetrySettings().toBuilder()
            .setTotalTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(30))
            .build());
SubscriberStubSettings subscriberStubSettings = subscriberStubSettingsBuilder.build();
```

This is based on the SubscriberStubSettings documentation [here](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-clients/latest/com/google/cloud/pubsub/v1/stub/SubscriberStubSettings.html).

Comment: I see. Thank you

Comment: The code sample I originally posted was incorrect; it never actually called setRetrySettings(). I've updated the sample and the documentation examples are in the process of being updated now as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since I wasn't able to make this work using [Lauren's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59886327/5297195) here is my take.
You could create a `ApiCallContext` object with default settings (or otherwise if you want) and set the timeout of your choice there. Then, you have to pass this ApiCallContext while `call`ing the `pullCallable`.
It might not be the only way but it makes sense in terms of context. Basically, what you want, is to set the blocking timeout in the API pull call.
The below answer is tested for `v1.126.1`:

```java
GrpcCallContext apiCallContext = GrpcCallContext.createDefault() 
 .withTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(30));
subscriber.pullCallable().call(pullRequest, apiCallContext);
```

This way, the `call` method will return after 30 seconds.